# Cambiar numero de elementos mostrados en combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Actualmente tengo un Combobox el cual, al desplegarlo, me muestra 6 elementos.

[image: Combo desplegado]

Me gustaría que, aunque se pueda pinchar en la esquina de abajo derecha para cambiar su tamaño, que, al desplegarlo, ya mostrase por ejemplo 10 valores y no los 6 que veo ahora.

He probado cambiando las propiedades MaxDropDownItems y la propiedad DropDownHeight y con ninguna consigo el comportamiento que busco.

Comment: Hola Pablo, si pones el código intento ayudarte con el tema, muchas gracias. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Robert Gutiérrez. El combobox lo que puesto desde la parte de diseño de Visual Studio, no lo genero desde código. Cargo sus datos con una consulta sql. Dime que código quieres ver y lo pongo. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Pablo, entiendo entonces que esos datos que veo en el CB viene de una BD, de acuerdo, en un hueco hago una simulación y te digo algo. Un saludo.

Comment: Si, cargo el combo con una consulta a BBDD, el resultado lo cargo en el DataSource del combo.

Comment: Hablamos de winforms?

Comment: Pikoh, hablamos de Formulario de Windows si, pero acabo de ver que es una clase propia creada para que dentro del combobox se muestren checks. Voy a ver si doy con el chiste y publicaré la respuesta por si a alguien le va bien.

Comment: En ese caso, la respuesta es sencilla: Pon las propiedades del `ComboBox` `IntegralHeight` a `false`, y en `MaxDropDownItems` el numero de elementos que quieres mostrar

Comment: Pruebo y te digo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Perdona, acabo de ver que habias cambiado ya `MaxDropDownItems`. Pero probablemente no te funcionó por el `IntegralHeight`. Prueba a ponerle a `false`

Comment: Nada, poniendo esas dos propiedades con los valores que me dices (en MaxDropDownItems le he puesto 15) y no, sigue todo igual.

Comment: En ese caso, el problema vendra por ser una clase custom supongo. Yo acabo de probar con un combo normal y se limitan los items perfectamente